Is there an error bound for perturbation theory?
It is usually said that perturbation theory is valid when the perturbation is much smaller than the spacing between energy levels. However, I was thinking whether there exists an rigorous error bound.
Let's say that we want to find eigenvalues $E_n$ of the Hamiltonian $H^{(0)}+H^{(1)}$, where $E_n^{(0)}$ are the eigenvalues of $H^{(0)}$. The condition as usually stated would then be
$|E_n^{(0)}-E_m^{(0)}|\ll H_{mn}^{(1)}$.
However, I am asking whether there is an error bound of the form
$$|E_n-(E_n^{(0)}+E_n^{(1)})|\ll \cdots,$$
where the RHS probably depends on the energy level spacing $|E_n^{(0)}-E_m^{(0)}|$ and matrix elements $H^{(1)}_{mn}$ (probably somehow "averaging" or "maximizing" over all values of $m$).
Additionally, is there an error bound on the wavefunctions as well? I would assume than an $L^2$ norm would be a natural "error" in this case:
$$\int |\psi_n - (\psi_n^{(0)} + \psi_n^{(1)})|^2 d\tau \ll \cdots$$
Even in case there is no rigorous result for QM Hamiltonians (e.g. due to complications with continuous spectra, ...), there might be a result for finite-dimensional vector spaces?

Say your Hamiltonian is of the form:
$$
H=H^{(0)}+\lambda V
$$
with $H^{(0)}$ the unperturbed Hamiltonian (hermitian operator), $V$ the perturbation (hermitian operator) and $\lambda$ a small real parameter. I’ll assume that you are asking in the context of non degenerate perturbation theory, i.e. $H^{(0)}$ is non degenerate. I will only treat the finite dimensional case with dimension $N$.
Perturbation theory amounts to expressing the eigenvalues of $H$, $E_n$, as a power series in $\lambda$:
$$
E_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda^k E_n^{(k)}
$$
Your question amounts to finding the region of validity of perturbation theory which is valid when $\lambda\to0$. What is the quantity to compare $\lambda$ to?
You can be interested in the validity of the truncated series up to order $k$. Assuming that you are in the asymptotic regime, the error is given by the $k+1$ term, so you get the region of validity for the $n$th eigenvalue:
$$
\lambda \ll \lambda_n^{(k)}:= \frac{E_n^{(k)}}{E_n^{(k+1)}}
$$
So for it to be valid for the entire spectrum:
$$
\lambda \ll \lambda^{(k)}:= \sup_n\frac{E_n^{(k)}}{E_n^{(k+1)}}
$$
This approach is quite common in physics, but is mathematically a bit unsatisfying. Appealing to the general theory of power series, a mathematically unambiguous quantity is rather $\lambda_n^{(\infty)}$, the radius of convergence of $E_n$. By the ratio test, if $(\lambda_n^{(k)})_{k\geq0}$ converges, then:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \lambda_n^{(k)}= \lambda_n^{(\infty)}
$$
which motivates the notation.
Practically estimating the radii of convergence from $H^{(0)}$ and $V$ is difficult in general. Indeed, it requires a general knowledge of $H$ which you typically do not have (after all, that’s why you want to apply perturbation theory in the first place). You can understand why they are finite though. The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $H$ whose coefficients depend polynomially in $\lambda$. The roots should be viewed as the $N$ branches of the Riemann surface obtained by inverting the polynomial. The dependence in the coefficients is analytic as long as the polynomial is nondegenerate. When roots collide, you have a branch point. Therefore, the radius of convergence is the smallest modulus of $\lambda$ such that $H$ is degenerate. Furthermore, $\lambda_n^{(\infty)}$ does not depend on $n$, so I will write the common value $\lambda^{(\infty)}$.
Note that it is not really level crossing since for complex $\lambda$, $H$ is not hermitian anymore. In fact, generically, $H$ has no level crossing if you only allow $\lambda$ to be real since degenerate Hamiltonians have real codimension larger than $1$.
You can build intuition by studying the case $N=2$. Choosing a basis where $H^{(0)}$ is diagonal, you can check that:
$$
\lambda^{(\infty)} = \frac{|E_2^{(0)}-E_1^{(0)}|}{\sqrt{4|V_{12}|^2+(V_{23}-V_{11})^2}}
$$
Hope this helps.
